# SSIS Slowly changing dimension column

Tags: ssis, etl, scd, scd2

I'm using a Slowly Changing Dimension in SSIS and I'm using a single column called active of type BIT to determine the latest records instead of start date and end date column.
My problem is the following: I want to turn the active value to 0 for records that are no more present in the source file.
For example imagine if my DWH is empty and in the source file I have the following data(Salary is the historisation attribute):
**employee_ID|NAME|salary**
**117|a|100**
**125|b|150**
**378|c|200**

Now once I charge those into my DWH I get the following data.
**employee_code|employee_ID|NAME|salary|active**
**1|117|a|100|1**
**2|125|b|150|1**
**3|378|c|200|1**

everything is good so far but now imagine I get a new source where the data is like this:
**employee_ID|NAME|salary**
**117|a|120**
**125|b|150**

Here when I charge this data in the datawarehouse I get the following:
**employee_code|employee_ID|NAME|salary|active**
**1|117|a|100|0**
**2|125|b|150|1**
**3|378|c|200|1**
**4|117|a|120|1**

Everything makes sense. Employee A's salary has changed so a new record is added in the DWH and the old record's active value turned to 0. Employee b's salary stayed the same so there is no need to add a new record. However mployee C does not exist in the source file anymore (He quit or got fired) I want to know if there is a way to turn the active value to 0 in such a situation

Comment: I have edited your question for clarity - please review and make sure it's correct. Firstly, why aren't you using effective from / to columns? There isn't a lot of use in storing historical changes if you don't know when they were were active or what order they are in. If you know for sure that an absence of an employee in a file means they quite (and you want to turn their record to inactive, then it's simply a matter of writing the correct code to do this. Normally there would be information in a header record somewhere with a termination date and that is a more reliable method.

Comment: Also just confirming: are you using the SSIS SCD component? Because it really is an absolutely terrible  component for many reasons.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thank you for your edit yes everything is correct.

Comment: I'm not using the from/to columns because I actually don't need to since I have in another table each employee_code associated with a reporting date. I already found a solution to my problem and as you suggested I ended up adding some code. What I did was I added a new task flow where I used the DWH table employees as a source and then performed a no correspondence lookup on the new source file to get hold of the records that are no longer active and need to be turned inactive and then I added an Ole db command where the code is  `Update employee Set active = 0 where employee_id = ?`.

Comment: Yes I'm using the SCD component. I'm new to SSIS(ETL tools in general) and I'm looking forward to learn more about it so if you can tell me what do you think is wrong with the SCD component that would be great.

Comment: There are a lot of problems with the SCD component, but the two main ones are: 1. It's a "destructive edit". If you need to change something you need to go through the whole wizard again, and you better get every tick and option right, otherwise it's going to create a different set of objects and your transform will start working differently, which is disasterous. 2. Terrible performance as it does a row-byrow update. Anyway, it's probably best if you just use it and discover it yourself so you have something to compare to.

Comment: https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s421/scd-disadvantages.htm

Comment: _I'm not using the from/to columns because I actually don't need to since I have in another table each employee_code associated with a reporting date_ Just keep in mind whatever your solution is doesn't align with a well established definition of how to define an SCD. It really is false economy to put these dates in a different table, or do away with one of the dates. To make reporting simpler you need both from and to dates, and you need to put them in the same table. That's my advice but I suggest you go ahead with your design and see for yourself.